# DLookup 3075 Missing Operator Around NZ?

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2013

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Sites", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
rs.Requery
rs.MoveFirst
   If Nz(Me.Site_ID.Value) > 0 Then
      Me.H2OBillingIDlbl.Caption = DLookup("H2OBillingIDNum", "Sites", "H2OBillingIDNum = " & Me.txtHotelID)
   Else
      Me.H2OBillingIDlbl.Caption = ""
   End If

End Sub
```

The DLookup line is throwing the error.

`Me.txtHotelID` box is a text entry box on the form and is used to enter numbers only.

The `H2OBillingIDNum` field in the recordset is Long.

I have tried putting brackets around `H2OBillingIDNum`; `.Value` at the end of `H2OBillingIDNum` and `Me.txtHotelID` alternatively and combined; entering the data as a string in which case I get data mismatch error.

I don't believe I can use a SQL query because it is a text entry field, but if I'm wrong, I'll happily take the information as I've never heard of a SQL query like that and it's a faster and more accurate method of pulling the data.

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions? Is it the NZ? Is there a better way of writing that? Should that not be included at all? If it helps, this is a DAO db.

Comment: What is `rs` for? And please add some line breaks in the text to make it better readable.

Comment: Hello, Andre, good to talk to you again! My apologies for lack of line breaks. I forgot to include this line: `Dim rs As recordset` and now I've edited original post for readability. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is still rather confusing though - there is no Nz() in your code. Or is `Sites` a query that uses Nz()? Then please add its SQL.

Comment: And with `rs`: You open it, but then don't use anything from it. Both `rs.Requery` and `rs.MoveFirst` are unnecessary after opening a recordset.

Comment: You can find the Nz here: `If Nz(Me.Site_ID.Value) > 0 Then` on the 6th line down, including the blank line. Good to know about the recordset; I thought it might be redundant. I'll remove it. Sites is a table, not a query.

Comment: Oops. Sorry for being blind. Although Nz() has defaults for its second parameter, it is clearer to explicitly specify it: `Nz(Me.Site_ID.Value, 0)`. Is it intentional that you check for `Site_ID` but run your DLookup on `txtHotelID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error must be that `Me.txtHotelID` is empty, therefore your `DLookup` call is incomplete

```
DLookup("foo", "bar", "myValue = ")
```

gives `Runtime error 3075: Syntax error (missing operator) in 'myValue = '`

Here is a guide on how to debug problems like this.

Take the code apart (one command per line), and use intermediate variables. Their values can be seen in break mode by hovering the mouse on the variable name, or in the Watch window.

Recommended reading: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

If you use `DLookup`, there is no need at all for a recordset, so I have removed it.

Run (or step through) this code, and the error will become clear:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim SiteID As Long
    Dim HotelID As Long
    Dim strCaption As String

    SiteID = Nz(Me.Site_ID.Value, 0)
    If SiteID > 0 Then
        ' Intentionally without Nz(), will throw error
        HotelID = Me.txtHotelID
        ' Nz() will be needed here too!
        strCaption = DLookup("H2OBillingIDNum", "Sites", "H2OBillingIDNum = " & HotelID)
    Else
        strCaption = ""
    End If
    Me.H2OBillingIDlbl.Caption = strCaption

End Sub
```

Comment: You are FANTASTIC! That was exactly it, thank you! I am clearing the final dregs of errors from the db, and I truly appreciate the help. AWESOME, DUDE!

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Caption As String

    If Nz(Me!Site_ID.Value, 0) > 0 Then
        SQL = "Select Top 1 H2OBillingIDNum From Sites Where H2OBillingIDNum = " & Nz(Me!txtHotelID.Value, 0) & ""
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SQL", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        Caption = rs!Fields(0).Value
    End If
    Me!H2OBillingIDlbl.Caption = Caption

    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

As you can see, it doesn't make much sense, as you look up `H2OBillingIDNum` which you already have as `Me!txtHotelID.Value`, so it probably should read:

```
SQL = "Select Top 1 SomeTextField From Sites Where H2OBillingIDNum = ...
```

Comment: Gustav, I am a newbie, and you're right, I'm really confused. I've never seen SQL queries like either of the ones you gave, and I would not know how to finish the second one. The `Fields(0).Value` field is not one of my fields, unless you were saying to use that in place of my field, or should I use that actual wording (is it a variable?), or not at all and use just the last SQL statement instead of my DLookup line my original code? Yep, I'm confused, and frustrated, I'm so sorry.

Comment: Fields(0) is just the first (and here only) field. There is no "second one" just an alternative to the SQL line in the function above. Replace `SomeTextField` with the name of your field holding the caption and, except for this, keep the original SQL sentence.

Comment: I think I'm probably still confused. Did you mean: `SQL = "Select Top 1 Me.H2OBillingIDlbl.Caption From Sites Where H2OBillingIDNum = " & Nz(Me!txtHotelID.Value, 0) & ""`    and     `Caption = rs!H2OBillingIDNum.Value`   and    `Me!H2OBillingIDlbl.Caption = Caption`

Comment: I tried the SQL query in every possible way I could think of and received error 3078, cannot find the input table or query SQL, make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. I even checked to see if adding a semicolon at or near the end would help, which it did not, just in case. I also tried substituting `txtHotelID` as an option, same result. My goal is to have Access display the HotelIDNum of the record in the caption if there is a positive match between the text entry and the recordset.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry misunderstod you
I don't really see the purpose, but one thing is sure - if your Dlookup returns a Null you get ant error. You cannot load the caption with null.
An NZ around the Dlookup is needed. But i don't know if it is possible that the Dlookup doesn't find anything

Comment: Soren, did you mean `DLookup("H2OBillingIDNum", "Sites", "H2OBillingIDNum = '" & Me.txtHotelID & "'")` ? If so, I have tried that, but as I stated, the entry is numerical, as is the field it is being matched to, and as such, it then throws a data mismatch error. I wish a string worked!

Comment: If txtHotelId is a txt field you have to convert to numric Clng(). You need to both sides as same type

Comment: Soren, I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by "Clng()". Both sides are Long, which was why I did not use string. I tried renaming the textbox on the form "numHotelID", changing the code to `DLookup("H2OBillingIDNum", "Sites", "H2OBillingIDNum = " numHotelID)` and got the same error. Is that where you were going?

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstod totally.